# jquery - scrollTo rescrolls the element FIDDLE

Tags: javascript, jquery

[FIDDLE here](https://jsfiddle.net/e4mbv387/1/).

My `scrollTo` function behaves abnormally. For some reason it is re-scrolling my page.

```
  $(container)
    .find('#btnRoles')
    .on('click', function() {
      $('.div-carousel').show();
      rescrollCar(this);
    });

  function rescrollCar(e) {
    $(window).scrollTo($(e), 400, {
      offset: { left: 100, top: -80 },
      queue: false
    });
  }

 function rescrollCar(e) {
    $(window).scrollTo($(e), 400, {
      offset: { left: 100, top: -80 },
      queue: false
    });
  }
```

After clicking the `search button`, For some reason it scrolls down and scrolls back. Full code on the [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/e4mbv387/1/)

Comment: None of it is here, but in your fiddle, on clicking that button, but `rescroll` and `rescrollCar` are called. I'd look in to that.

Comment: @PaulRoub, m not sure how to restrict the `rescroll` part. It should ideally not trigger.

Comment: Please be clear in the question *exactly* what you are expecting you code to be doing, and *exactly* what it's doing wrong. Please include enough code *in the question* to duplicate the problem. This question is about JavaScript/HTML/CSS, so you should strongly consider using a [snippet](//blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/), which would allow people to test the code without having to go off-site. Using a snippet usually results in a post (question or answer) being received better (i.e. more up-votes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it behaves like this is, that the `click` event of your input block is triggered a second time after the scroll happens, so the `rescroll()` is called again.

change to `mousedown` event and it should work.

```
$(container)
  .find('.input-block')
  .not('.input-block input, .first-element')
  .on('mousedown', function() {
   rescroll(this);      
});
```